# Laravel combination Routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i have any route in routes.php for redirect to show `index.blade.php` view.

my route are such as:

```
Route::get('admin/index', array('as'=>'dashboard', function()
{
    return View::make('back_end.layouts.index');
}));

Route::get('admin', array('as'=>'dashboard', function()
{
    return View::make('back_end.layouts.index');
}));

Route::get('index', array('as'=>'dashboard', function()
{
    return View::make('back_end.layouts.index');
}));
```

i want to combination this routes like with this :

```
Route::get(array('index','admin/index','admin'), array('as'=>'dashboard', function()
{
    return View::make('back_end.layouts.index');
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions to filter your routes:

```
Route::get('{page}', function()    
{
    return View::make('back_end.layouts.index');
})->where('page', 'index|admin/index|admin');
```

But you cannot have the same name for 3 different routes, how could Laravel choose one if you have the same name?

Answer (score 1):

Really you're asking the wrong question. The situation you have found yourself in is that you want three entirely different URIs to act as one.

What you really want is one canonical route for the dashboard, and the two other routes to redirect to that route.

As such, your routes file is much better as:

```
<?php

// one true canonical route
Route::get('admin', array('as'=>'dashboard', function()
{
    return View::make('back_end.layouts.index');
}));

// two routes to redirect to dashboard
Route::get('index', function()
{
    return Redirect::route('dashboard');
});
// two routes to redirect to dashboard
Route::get('admin/index', function()
{
    return Redirect::route('dashboard');
});
```

That said, you shouldn't even have to care about those extra routes, as you'll never link to them, so they're only there to help people who type them directly, which is relatively unlikely.

Comment: thanks, i get error: `ErrorException  
trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
open: /var/www/alachiq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php`

Comment: Sorry, I assumed the array syntax that Antonia Carlos Ribeiro (who I also incorrectly credited as you, d'oh) used would work. (Though I did happen to mention I'd never seen it before.) Anyway, I've corrected the code to not use it but instead bind two routes for the redirects. Try that.